# dynamically set width of ul based on combined width of li tags

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm trying to create a horizontal tab menu.  how can i get the combined width of all the li tags and assign the width to the parent UL using jquery?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I'd agree with Akoi, I think this is probably one for CSS. Something like

```
<style type="text/css">
ul { overflow: auto; background: #efefef; padding: 0; margin: 0; display: block; float: left; clear: both; }
ul li { float: left; display: block; padding: 5px 10px; }
</style>

<ul>
  <li>Menu item</li>
  <li>Menu item</li>
  <li>Menu item</li>
  <li>Menu item</li>
  <li>Menu item</li>
  <li>Menu item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The fact that the ul is floated left means it will only extend horizontally to the width of it's contents.

The overflow means it will stretch horizontally AND vertically so you don't have to set the height.

The clear ensures nothing will try and sit next to it. 

Have you tried this code?

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiosity, why are you having to specify the width anyways? You should just be able to float your LI's left in css, then clear them with a handy <br />.

```
<style type="text/css">
ul li { float: left; }
br { clear: both; }
</style>

<ul>
<li>Some</li>
<li>randomly long</li>
<li>or</li>
<li>short</li>
<li>LI's</li>
</ul><br />
```

Comment: i want to specify the width of the ul because i have a background on it and I don't want it to stretch to the width of my container.

Comment: yea my problem isn't with floating the li's

Comment: Do you have the page up anywhere to look at?

Answer (score 0):

here's my html.  as you can see, I'm only trying to ensure that my ul doesn't extend to the width of the container.

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
$("#tabs").tabs();
    });
   </script>
<style>
#container {width:960px;}
#tabs {background:url(../images/tab_lft.gif) no-repeat 0 0; margin:0 10px; width:940px;}
#tabs ul {background:#ccc url(../images/tab_rgt.gif) no-repeat right 0; height:24px; list-style:none; margin:0 0 0 6px; padding:6px 6px 0 0; }
#tabs ul li {display:inline; float:left; line-height:24px;}
#tabs ul li a:link, #tabs ul li a:visited {display:block; color:#565656; padding:0 10px; text-decoration:none; }
#tabs ul li a:hover {background-color:#fff;}
.clear {clear: both; display: block; overflow: hidden; visibility: hidden; width: 0; height: 0;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="tab1.html">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="tab2.html">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="tab3.html">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```